# A problem on sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to know example of a sequence of function $\{f_n\}$ where each $f_n$ is continuous and the pointwise limit $f$ is continuous, but $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent. clearly, I need to think for a $f_n$ where there exist an $x$ such that $f_n(x)$ is not monotone.

Comment: or even nicer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405644/does-pointwise-convergence-against-a-continuous-function-imply-uniform-convergen